# Why is L'Hopital's rule failing for this Fourier Coefficient?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-series

I am currently doing extra practice problems before my Differential Equations final and found a seemingly straight-forward Fourier Series problem for which I cannot find the n=1 term for. The problem is:

$$f(x) = \begin {cases} 0, -\pi<x<0 \\ sin(x), 0<x<\pi \end{cases}$$

The solution in the back of the book is:

$$ f(x) = \frac{1}\pi + \frac{sin(x)}2 + \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n +1}{1-n^2}cos(nx)$$

I am having trouble getting the $\frac{sin(x)}2$ term. I am currently attempting to evaluate the summand at n=1 using L'Hopital's rule, however this is failing to yield the correct value. I have attempted to do this using two forms of the summand:

1. $$\lim_{n\to 1} \frac{cos(n\pi)+1}{1-n^2}cos(nx) = \frac{0}{0}$$
   Applying L'Hopital's rule this is equal to:
   $$\lim_{n\to 1}\frac{(-\pi sin(n\pi)cos(nx)) + (cos(n\pi)+1)(-xsin(nx))}{-2n}=\frac{0}{-2} = 0$$
2. $$\lim_{n\to 1} \frac{(-1)^n + 1}{1-n^2}cos(nx) = \frac{0}{0}$$
   Again applying L'Hopital's rule:
   $$\lim_{n\to 1} \frac{(n(-1)^{n-1} cos(nx))+((-1)^n + 1)(-xsin(nx))}{-2n}=\frac{cos(x)+0}{-2}=\frac{cos(x)}{-2}$$

I have a feeling L'Hopital's rule is not valid to use here due the summand not being a continuous function in n, but I am unsure what alternative's there are. The only other thing I can think of would be that there is another way to express this but I cannot think of any. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fourier coefficient $a_n $ for $n=1$ is given by the following fomula:
$$a_1=\frac {1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f (x) \cos x dx$$
$$=\frac {1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin x \cdot \cos x dx$$
$$= \frac {1}{\pi} \cdot \frac {\cos 2x}{2}|_{0}^{\pi} $$
$$=0$$

And the fourier coefficient $b_n $ for $n=1$ is given by the following fomula:
$$b_1=\frac {1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f (x) \sin x dx$$
$$=\frac {1}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \sin x \cdot \sin x dx$$
$$= \frac {1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac {1-\cos 2x}{2} dx$$
$$=\frac {1}{\pi} \cdot (\frac {\pi}{2}-0)$$
$$=\frac {1}{2}$$

So the term $b_1 \sin x = \frac {\sin x}{2}$

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you that does. I was thinking it might come from the b_1 term but convinced myself otherwise because the general form I found appeared to equal zero for all n. I will definitely have to be more careful with these cases.